# Transform a positive integer to find its next greatest factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

Suppose I am trying to find factors of a particular positive integer `num`. Suppose I also have a function `findGreatestFactor(num)` that finds the greatest factor of a positive integer.

Is there a way to transform my integer `num` such that it would still have all of the same factors as the original `num` but `findGreatestFactor(num)` would find the *next* greatest factor of the original `num`?

Example:

```
let num = 100

findGreatestFactor(num) gives you 50 (the greatest factor of 100)

let num2 = some transformation of num

findGreatestFactor(num2) gives you 25 (the second greatest factor of 100)

let num3 = same transformation of num2

findGreatestFactor(num3) gives you 20 (the third greatest factor of 100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider the prime factorization $N = p_1 ^{q_1} \times p_2 ^{q_2} \times \ldots \times {p_n}^q_n$, where the $p_i$ are arranged in increasing order, then the smallest proper factor is $p_1$, and the next smallest factor is either $p_1 ^2 $ or $p_2$.

Hence. Let $FGF$ be your findgrestestfactor. $Num/FGF(Num)$ will give you $p_1$. $Take FGF(Num)$ and divide out by $p_1$ repeatedly until we no longer get an integer. Say that the last integer is $N_1$. Then taking $\frac {N_1} {FGF(N_1)}$ will give you $p_2$. If $p_1^2 \not \mid N$, then $p_2$ is the second smallest factor. Otherwise, compare $p_1 ^2 $ and $p_2$. Whichever is smaller, then $N/x$, will give you the second smallest factor.

Comment: This seems to be spot on for what OP wants.

Comment: This shows that it is indeed possible to get the second largest factor from the FGF function, but it's not quite as straight forward as the OP wnated it.

Comment: this looks to be what I need. I will try it out when I get home later and accept if I get it working. Thank you.

Comment: @jbabey Note: Slight change to account for case where $p_1^2 \not \mid N$, doesn't really affect anything.

Comment: @CalvinLin what if the factors i'm looking for are not always prime?

Comment: @jbabey The largest factors need not be prime. The first smallest (proper) factor will always be prime (otherwise, take any of its prime factors). The second smallest (proper) factor need not be prime, which is why I broke it up into the $p_1^2$ and $p_2$ case. Try out my procedure on 100 (where $2^2 < 5$) and on 60 (where $2^2 > 3$). You should obtain 25 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, num2 would have 25 as greatest factor and 20 as second greatest factor. Then num2 must be a multiple of 100, and the greatest factor of num2 would be at least 50.

So this is impossible.